# What is the best way to iterate inside WSO2 EI?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, mediator, ei, wso2-esb

After reading of WSO2 EI References, I still confuse about how use iterators inside a EI sequence.
        In my case I have a payload like this....

```
   {
...
   "array": [
    {"cpf": "12345678911"},
    {"cnpj":"12345678912346"}
   ]
}
```

So I have to iterate to check if those guys exist using another web services. in order to achieve that flow, I am using the iterate mediator to split the message and then building the logic to make those validations as follows..

[image]

The code that implements this image is following:

```
 <iterate description="" expression="//jsonObject/array" id="myid">
                        <target>
                            <sequence>
                                <property expression="json-eval($.array.cpf)" name="tipoCPF" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                <filter description="" xpath="boolean(get-property('tipoCPF'))">
                                    <then>
                                        <property expression="json-eval($.array.cpf)" name="uri.var.cpf" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

                                        <call>
                                            <endpoint>
                                                <http method="get" uri-template="http://endpoint/service/{uri.var.cpf}"/>
                                            </endpoint>
                                        </call>
                                        <filter regex="200" source="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')">
                                            <then/>
                                            <else>
                                                <payloadFactory description="" media-type="json">
                                                    <format>{&#xd;
"code":"400",&#xd;
"error":"CPF inexistente"&#xd;
}</format>
                                                    <args/>
                                                </payloadFactory>
                                                <property name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="400"/>
                                                <respond/>
                                            </else>
                                        </filter>
                                    </then>
                                    <else>
                                        <property expression="json-eval($.array.cnpj)" name="tipoCNPJ" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                        <filter xpath="boolean(get-property('tipoCNPJ'))">
                                            <then>
                                                <property expression="json-eval($.array.cnpj)" name="uri.var.cnpj" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                                <header name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Basic Y29yZS5jb25zdWx0aW5nOm8xNXRyZWI="/>
                                                <call>
                                                    <endpoint>
                                                        <http method="get" uri-template="http://endpoint/service/cnpj/{uri.var.cnpj}"/>
                                                    </endpoint>
                                                </call>
                                                <filter regex="200" source="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')">
                                                    <then/>
                                                    <else>
                                                        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                                                            <format>{&#xd;
        "code":"400",&#xd;
        "error":"CNPJ inexistente"&#xd;
        }</format>
                                                            <args/>
                                                        </payloadFactory>
                                                        <property name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="400"/>
                                                        <respond/>
                                                    </else>
                                                </filter>
                                            </then>
                                            <else>
                                                <call>
                                                    <endpoint>
                                                        <http method="get" uri-template="http://endpoint/service/info"/>
                                                    </endpoint>
                                                </call>
                                            </else>
                                        </filter>
                                    </else>
                                </filter>
                            </sequence>
                        </target>
                    </iterate>
```

This iterator work as part inside of the an 'insequence'. The 'Insequence' is deigned to allow to insert new contracts information inside the Database.
**Problem:** after add this iterator, the service starts to make duplicated insertions inside Database. It´s looks like the iteration don´t finish in the edge of tags 'iterator'. It´s like the iteration continues to the rest of insequence.
**Try:** In order to solve this problem i try to add an aggregator mediator after the iterator. But or doesn't have any effect end the duplicated insert persist, or I receive an error message.

***So What is the correct whey to make this iterations inside WSO2 EI?***

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, Iteration will occur even outside the iterate tag, until the Aggregate mediator is used. To resolve this issue, you need to add the aggregate mediator **inside** the iterate mediator. This will stop the iteration within the iterator tag itself.

For your use case, you may need to set `continueParent="true"` in the **IterateMediator**, so that the mediation will continue after the iterate mediator for the insertion Operation in database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helping Arunan! 

After your answer I try to add the Aggregator as follows
[image: Adding the Aggregator Mediator]

The config of aggregator is following:

```
...
 <aggregate id="NIRO">
                                    <completeCondition>
                                        <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
                                    </completeCondition>
                                    <onComplete expression="//jsonObject">
                                        <log description="" level="full" separator=";">
                                            <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="jsonObject"/>
                                        </log>
                                    </onComplete>
                                </aggregate>
                            </sequence>
                        </target>
                    </iterate>
```

As you sad I change the iterator property '`Continue Parent`' to '`true`'. But the problem persists....

Comment: Are you still getting duplicate entries?

Comment: Yes! The problem persists!

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the full synapse configuration (with sensitive information removed)?

Comment: Where can I found this configuration?

Comment: The source view of the mediation flow you have show above in the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed in the other answer, you need to

- use an **Aggregate** mediator to close the iteration
- If and only if the **Iterator** is set to `continueParent="true"`

However, I am not sure that putting it **inside** the `<iterate>` works. Here is a working solution using an **Aggregate** mediator **right after** your **Iterator**.

```xml
<sequence>
    <iterate continueParent="true" description="" expression="//jsonObject/array" id="myid">
        <target>
            <your_sequence />
        </target>
    </iterate>
    <aggregate>
        <completeCondition>
            <messageCount max="-1" min="-1" />
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="//jsonObject/array" expression="/whatever/you/want"/>
    </aggregate>
</sequence>
```

Notice `expression="//jsonObject/array"` you used in your **Iteration**, you'll need to use it in the **Aggregator**'s `enclosingElementProperty`.  This is how your EI will know from which iterator it should aggregate from (not 100% sure about this point, more of an empirical consideration).